# deleting first row based on column variable

Tags: r

How do I delete the first row of each new variable? For example, here is some data:

```
m <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b") 
n <- c('x','y','x','y','x','y',"x","y",'x',"y") 
o <- c(1:10)

z <- data.frame(m,n,o)
```

I want to delete the first entry for a and b in column m. I have a very large data frame so I want to do this based on the change from a to b and so on.

Here is what I want the data frame to look like.

```
  m n  o
1 a y  2
2 a x  3
3 a y  4
4 a x  5
5 b x  7
6 b y  8
7 b x  9
8 b y 10
```

Thanks.

Comment: See `?duplicated` - i.e. `duplicated(z$m)` gives you a logical vector that you can use for selections.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The entries are not duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `duplicated`:

```
z[duplicated(z$m),]

#   m n  o
#2  a y  2
#3  a x  3
#4  a y  4
#5  a x  5
#7  b x  7
#8  b y  8
#9  b x  9
#10 b y 10
```

Why this works? Consider:

```
duplicated("a")
#[1] FALSE
duplicated(c("a","a"))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I don't know who dv'd, but this is brilliant

Answer (score 4):

data.table is preferred for large datasets in R. `setDT` converts `z` data frame to data table by reference. Group by `m` and remove the first row.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(z)[, .SD[-1], by = "m"]
```

Comment: `z[z[, .I[-1], by=m]$V1]` would probably be faster

Comment: @RichScriven - didn't `.SD[n]` get optimised a while back?

Comment: Did it?  I might have missed that.

Comment: @RichScriven - I can't seem to find the reference to it now - maybe I imagined it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `group_by` and `row_number`from package dplyr:

```
z %>% 
  group_by(m) %>%
  filter(row_number(o)!=1)
```